# Discord.py Bot - How to mention random user

Tags: python, discord, bots

I'm making a Discord Bot in Python, and currently I want to add a feature, when a bot mention random user with the command `_best`

I tried this code:

```py
if message.content.startswith('_best'):
    Channel = message.channel
    randomMember = random.choice(Channel.members)
    await message.channel.send(f'{randomMember.mention} is the best')
```

But the bot mention himself all over the time! Any ideas?

Comment: `message.channel.send(f'<@{randomMember.id}> is the best')` ?

Comment: @GhostOps, bot still mentions himself :(

Comment: what is Channel in there? voice channel, text channel, or the server?

Comment: This is text channel

Comment: so you want to ping a random guy in the server, isn't it?

Comment: @GhostOps The main point is when the user types command `_best`, the bot chooses all across the members randomly and says the message. It can be either ping or just a copied name (without ping)

Answer (score 1):

## Intents

---

You have to include the intents, like this:

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
Bot = discord.commands.Bot(intents=intents)
```

You must have enabled the intents from [`Discord developer portal`](https://discord.com/developers/applications).

## Members

---

It's better to use this code:

```
member = random.choice(message.guild.members)
```

since it includes all the users of the guild.

## Command

---

Why don't you use a `discord.Command`? Like this:

```
@Bot.command()
async def best(ctx):
    member = random.choice(ctx.guild.members)
    ctx.send(member.mention)
```

Comment: I have this error then:  `Bot = discord.Bot(intents=intents)
AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'Bot'`

Comment: You need to assign the bot variable to your main python command

Comment: I fixed it, it was discord.commands.Bot.  Then I meant that you had to add the intents with the Bot declaration.

Comment: Thank you really much! But, unfortunately, I'm getting [this](https://i.pinimg.com/564x/1f/4e/3a/1f4e3a6d346992469b477b54259f64c2.jpg) error (sorry for the low-quality image). **And also**: If I will change commands to `discord.Command` type, will I have to change all my bot's commands? (I mean, I won't really like changing 114 commands, you know :).)

Comment: @Aaron its actually `discord.ext.commands.Bot`

Answer (score 1):

Try `random.choice(message.guild.members)` instead of `random.choice(Channel.members)` to get the list of members in the server

Because getting a random member from a text channel is same as from the entire server

And then try `message.channel.send(f'{randomMember.mention} is the best')`

And also, the bot will mention only itself unless you enable the **Privileged Gateway Intents** for your bot by going to `https://discord.com/developers/applications/{your_bot's_client_id_goes_here}/bot` and enable **Server Members Intent** to make your bot get access to server members list

And also use `@bot.command` instead of tons of if-else statements for each command inside `on_message`

Code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot('_', intents=intents)

@bot.command()
async def best(ctx):
    randomMember = random.choice(ctx.guild.members)
    await ctx.send(f'{randomMember.mention} is the best')
```

---

If still the above code doesn't work for you...

Change this

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    # do all your stuff here
```

into this

```py
@bot.listen('on_message')
async def whatever_you_want_to_call_it(message):
    # do stuff here
    # do not process commands here
```

And if you still want to use the `on_message` with if statements, then use this code

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    randomMember = random.choice(message.guild.members)
    await message.channel.send(f'{randomMember.mention} is the best')
```

Tell me if its not working for you...

Comment: Thank you for your reply! But, unfortunately, the bot still mentions himself. P.S.: Bot **has** administrator permissions by the way :)

Comment: @Aaron sry, now i edited the answer, check it out!

Comment: Thank you for your advice! But, sadly, my bot is still mentioning himself.
  **1.** I tried to combine your answer with @FLAK-ZOSO's, so I got [this](https://i.pinimg.com/564x/65/b3/55/65b3550f823778978979c570e1ba3549.jpg) (This is a Pinterest image, don't worry). Outcome: Bot still mentions only himself.
**2.** Ok, I will listen to your advice, making commands `@bot.command`, but will I have to change all bot's commands? (I won't really like changing my bot's 114 commands you know :).)

Comment: @Aaron did you do like `intents.members = True` ? and also, you have to enable an option in the website that i mentioned in the answer. Have u done that too? And also, you haven't passed the intents to the bot class i guess...

Comment: Yes, I have added `intents.members = True` but the same problem. Also, yes, I checked Privileged Gateway Intents. But the one thing I don't understand is - How to pass intents to the bot class? (I'm a beginner in coding :).). Thank you

Comment: @Aaron `intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True` and `bot = commands.Bot('_', intents=intents)`

Comment: Sad to say, but I have tried all your 3 methods (`@bot.command()`, `@bot.event` and `@bot.listen('on_message')` but none of them worked. All of them have the same error: `AttributeError: module 'discord.ext.commands.bot' has no attribute 'listen'`.  But is there any way to do the same You advised, but in `if` type? Thank you once again :)

Comment: @Aaron hi, i edited the answer and added the code for that too, check it out! is it working now?